# How to add dynamically a required to an input element?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My task was to add a required fields dynamically to all of the elements on each state that the user wanted to set as required. In my database i have an table that contain the id of the input (to each input have a different id of course) and a required field that contain if we need to add a required field to the input element (boolean). Every time i switch states i need to set all the input elements to required (if there is required input elements) to that specific state.

who can i attack this? 
this is my soltion but id dont think this is the best way, i am working with angularjs.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {     
    // activate required function
    v = data[i].Required;
    if (v) {
        document.getElementById(data[i].ID).required = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what about jquery,  elem.attr('required')

Comment: Use jquery sparingly with angular.  In most cases you'll find that the framework already has a directive that'll handle your issue.  Look at ngRequired

Comment: When i open the development tool at google chrome, i can see that the required field has been added, but if i want to add an error to the html like: "This  field is required"  i can`t do that. If i write manually required to the html element i can check if its dirty or touched and add an error but when i add dynamically i can do that..any suggestion? @myke_11j @jbrown

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying the data also in angular, for example in a repeater, you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in data">
    <input type="text" id="{{ field.ID }}"
           ng-required="field.Required" />
</div>
```

The `ng-required` directive dynamically sets the `required="required"` attribute, based on the value of the `Required` property of the `field` item.

Comment: This solution can`t work for me because i have a function that responsible for every time that i change a state  sh puts the required fields to the input, and this function outside the controller that i working with ( i don`t have the data in my specific controller and i don`t want to pass that data)

Comment: Then you will have to include your use case in the question, be more specific in what you can and what you want to achieve

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way also.

```
<form name="course">
<div ng-repeat="field in data">
    <input type="text" name="{{field.name}}"
           ng-required="field.Required" />
</div>
</form>
```